# Google Analytics API Library

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking to see how we can allow a user to connect with their Google Analytic's User ID and connect with our app and we can get the information from their account.

I am looking forward to some articles or any library thats build around the same.

I will be using PHP and MySQL. Do you suggest any other Database than MySQL ?

Comment: Whats the duration you looking to store information for. Also will depend on whats the general visits/view of the sites which you want to   track. If the sites don't have much visits a db would work just fine.

Comment: @sesmic i am looking forward to storing data or rather updating the existing data once a week or so. Its basically to allow comparing two google analytics account data against each other

Comment: Certainly you could make use of the Google Analytics API.  If you don't want to get that involved with the API, you might consider some 3rd party solutions available form the [Apps Gallery](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps).  I actually have developed a reporting solution called [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  Our service allows you to do cross profile charts, and can be customized to fit in CMS type applications (which it sounds like you are doing).

Comment: @MSchenkel thank you. I am looking for some php clients so that i can work on the API. Can you suggest me which one i can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a database to keep things simple and since you are not looking to store too much of historical data. The link below should get you started with all the required libraries and documentation.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

Go for the web client based authentication model rather than the service account model.

This will cause the `api` to redirect your user to google authorization page and your app will be given privileges to user account.

Make sure you save the refresh token when it redirects back to you app.
Please note that the refresh token only get sent for the very first time you app asks for permission and not after that.